# Create an array of top 10 users based on follower count?

Tags: php, algorithm

I do not have much experience working with PHP, but I have developed a crude algorithm to determine the top 10 users on a social network in terms of number of followers. It does return a list of users that seems about right, but there are two problems with this that I can see:

1. It seems very repetitive and resource-intensive, especially if we have many users. Is there a simple way to short-circuit the algorithm if the user does not have more followers than the last position, while still maintaining the sort order? How can the algorithm be condensed/simplified?
2. It doesn't exactly work. The list of users that it returns isn't the top 10 users. For example, running the script now returns users with these follower counts (in order): 54, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1. These numbers seem about right, but I know for a fact that there are at least two other users that have higher follower counts than 54. Plus, the 5th user is out of place. Is this a problem with our algorithm or is the problem in something else (perhaps how we have the followers stored)?

Here's the code in question:

```
$array = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());;
for($i = 0; $user = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM); $i++) {
    if      (following($user[0]) > following($array[0])) $array[0] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[1])) $array[1] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[2])) $array[2] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[3])) $array[3] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[4])) $array[4] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[5])) $array[5] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[6])) $array[6] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[7])) $array[7] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[8])) $array[8] = $user[0];
    else if (following($user[0]) > following($array[9])) $array[9] = $user[0];
}
```

After this, it inputs the array into a MySQL table. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the code for the followers function.

```
        function followers($id){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE following='$id' AND follower!='$id'");
        return mysql_num_rows($query);
        }
```

Comment: use mysqli_* function instead of mysql_*....

Comment: where does `following` gets followers, database or an api call?

Comment: just an general advice: do not use `mysql_*`, try e.g. PDO instead: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: If the following count stored in the database for each user?

Comment: Why not just do it in mysql? `SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY followers DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Hint: You're an `else` short! ;)

Comment: Following determines the amount of followers by checking the amount of occurrences of a particular user ID in a follower-following table, with each row consisting of the two user IDs.

Comment: Please give us some more information: `table structure`, syntax of `following()` and your desired output. Maybe its possible with SQL.

Comment: @BenFortune Follower count is not stored in the users table. Refer to my comment above.

Comment: But it _is_ stored in another (detail) table in the DB, right?

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic Follower count is determined by method in my comment above. Table `users` consists of a row for each user, with columns for various information pertaining to that user, but nothing that relates to followers.

Comment: @geomagas It's stored in a table with each row being in the format of (follower UID), (following UID). The amount of occurrences of a target UID in the following column is the target user's follower count.

Comment: so, what does `following()` code do? access database and fetch followers count? if so, may be you could join and complete it in a query

Comment: @AustinBerke Please post your function `following()`. I think this should be done easy with SQL. As mentioned above, something like `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY followers DESC LIMIT 10` or, if the followers are counted in another table, you've to use join or subquery for example.

Comment: @AustinBerke: I'm trying to make you post your table structure, but since you haven't yet, please see my answer anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic Added followers function.

Comment: @AustinBerke take a look at my answer below. You can do this with a simple SQL query. You don't need the followers function. :-)

Comment: @AustinBerke: But you use a follow**ing** function instead!

Comment: @geomagas Wow, I cannot believe I didn't catch that. That fixes the second issue, but I'll still look into fixing the efficiency of the algorithm. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AustinBerke: As I said, check out my answer, as well as others'. If nothing else, there's a lot _food for thought_ down the page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. Depends on your table structure. In this case I wouldn't sort with PHP. It's simple and fast with SQL.

If the followers are stored in the user table:

```
SELECT *                // try to avoid *
  FROM `users`
 ORDER BY followers DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

If the followers are stored in another table (**Edit**: adapted to your structure:):

```
SELECT u.user_id, COUNT(*) AS num_followers
  FROM `users` u, `follow` f
 WHERE u.user_id = f.following
 GROUP BY u.user_id
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't just `SELECT * FROM users`. Try

```
select u.userId,count(*) as n
from users u,followers f
where u.userId=f.following
group by u.userId
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
```

The field names are imaginary, since I don't know your actual table structure (**edit**: just changed `f.userId` to `f.following`, but `users` structure remains unknown).

This will give you the top 10 group you want, and make it a lot easier to iterate with PHP.

**EDIT**: To elaborate a bit, let the RDBMS do the relation, aggregate, and sorting job for you. That's its job and it performs well at it.

Answer (score 0):

there are many php functions for sorting, you don't have to write your own. http://php.net/manual/de/array.sorting.php